# Create a Pagination Carousel with jQuery Cycle?

Tags: jquery, pagination, cycle, carousel

I'm using malsup's amazing [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plug-in for a small gallery. I've created thumbnail pagination with this code:

```
$('#gallery').cycle({ 
    fx:     'fade', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 0, 
    pager:  '#pagination',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
    return '#pagination li:eq(' + idx + ') a'; 

    } 
 });
```

What I'd love to do is make the pagination a horizontal carousel using Cycle's built-in "scrollHoriz" effect, but I don't know how! I could use the jQuery Carousel plug-in, but it just seems silly to add a whole new plugin when I'm sure Cycle has the capability. Has anyone done this? Any suggestions on how I might go about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually youre better off using an actual carousel plugin like `jCarousel`. You could do it using cycle as the base, but there is a lot of additional functionality you would need to create - essentially writing your own plugin. Youre better off just using a carousel plugin form the start.

There is even a question somewhere on SO where the author of Cycle says as much :-)

Comment: Yea, that's a good point. I'll have to brush up on my jQuery and maybe I can write my own plug-in! Until then I'll just use jCarousel.Thanks, prodigitalson!